# Why use a char array to store contents of a file opened in binary mode?

Tags: c++, file, io

So from what I understand, when you open a file in binary mode using C++ the contents would be 0s and 1s right? If so, why would the official documentation about input/output with files use a char* array to store the contents? If we're only storing 0s and 1s, why not use a short/int?

Comment: Your point would be...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642381/c-c-why-to-use-unsigned-char-for-binary-data

Comment: What “official documentation”?

Comment: If you want to store the complete contents of an arbitrary file, then it won't necessarily fit exactly into a whole number of `int` values, say. In addition to that size issue you would need to deal with byte ordering within the `int`s, and even with `unsigned int` you run into the formal obstacle (but not a practical issue) that, depending on the implementation, not all bits in an `int` are necessarily value representation bits, and that there can be trap bit patterns. Still, for some other purpose, if part of a file represents `int`s directly, then the natural way to store that is as `int`s.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf um the docs on cplusplus.com

Comment: Your answer does make a lot of sense thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

The interpretations of `short` and `int` are architecture dependent while `char` is not. This is due to [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) where the bytes of these datatypes can be interpreted in different orders.

Comment: What about size of a char? Its sizeof 1 but how many bits is it?

Comment: The size of a byte is also implementation defined, but a `char` is a `char`, i.e. exactly one byte as enforced by the standard. Loading file data as a character array will introduce no byte-ordering ambiguity regardless of byte-size while `int` and `short` do introduce ambiguity.