# Char vs unsigned char for byte arrays

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

When storing "byte arrays" (blobs...) is it better to use `char` or `unsigned char` for the items (`unsigned char` a.k.a. `uint8_t`)? (Standard says that `sizeof` of both is precisely 1 Byte.)

Does it matter at all? Or one is more convenient or prevalent than the other? Maybe, what libraries like Boost do use?

Comment: @nightcracker Perhaps, could you point at the duplicate?

Comment: Dupe with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653336/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `char` is signed, then performing arithmetic on a byte value with the high bit set will result in sign extension when promoting to `int`; so, for example:

```
char c = '\xf0';
int res = (c << 24) | (c << 16) | (c << 8) | c;
```

will give `0xfffffff0` instead of `0xf0f0f0f0`.  This can be avoided by masking with `0xff`.

`char` may still be preferable if you're interfacing with libraries that use it instead of `unsigned char`.

Note that a cast from `char *` to/from `unsigned char *` is always safe (3.9p2).  A philosophical reason to favour `unsigned char` is that 3.9p4 in the standard favours it, at least for representing byte arrays that could hold memory representations of objects:

> The *object representation* of an object of type `T` is the sequence of `N` `unsigned char` objects taken up by the object of type `T`, where `N` equals `sizeof(T)`.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, the size of a byte in C++ is dependant on the compiler-settings and target platform, but it is guaranteed to be at least 8 bits, which explains why `sizeof(uint8_t)` is required to be 1.

Here's more precisely what the standard has to say about it

*§1.71*

> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A
>   byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic
>   execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the
>   Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence
>   of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined. The least
>   significant bit is called the low-order bit; the most significant bit
>   is called the high-order bit. The memory available to a C++ program
>   consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every byte has
>   a unique address.

So, if you are working on some special hardware where bytes are not 8 bits, it may make a practical difference. Otherwise, I'd say that it's a matter of taste and what information you want to communicate via the choice of type.

Answer (score 1):

One of the other problems with potentially using a signed value for blobs is that the value will depend on the sign representation, which is not part of the standard.  So, it's easier to invoke undefined behavior.

For example...

```
signed char x = 0x80;
int y = 0xffff00ff;

y |= (x << 8); // UB
```

The actual arithmetic value would also strictly depend two's complement, which may give some people surprises.  Using unsigned explicitly avoids these problems.

Answer (score 0):

makes no practcial difference although maybe from a readability point of view it is more clear if the type is `unsigned char` implying values 0..255.