# Unable to read a binary file into std::vector<std::byte> in C++

Tags: c++, io, byte, c++17, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a .WAV file in C++ into a vector of binary data:

```
typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> file_iterator;

std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (!file.is_open()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open " + path);
}

std::vector<std::byte> content((file_iterator(file)), file_iterator());
```

When I attempt to compile this code I get an error:

> Cannot convert 'char' to 'std::byte' in initialization

However if I change the vector to `std::vector<unsigned char>` it works fine.

Looking at the documentation for `std::byte` it looks like it is supposed to act like an `unsigned char` so I'm not sure where the compiler is getting confused.

Is there any particular way you are supposed to go about reading a file into a vector of bytes? (I am looking for a modern C++ approach)

---

I am using MinGW 7.3.0 as my compiler.

### EDIT:

This question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819820/char-vs-unsigned-char-for-byte-arrays) because I am specifically concerned about modern C++ techniques and the use of std::byte which is not discussed in that question.

Comment: `std::istreambuf_iterator<std::byte>` doesn't compile. I've been trying to wrap my head around why, but it seems like that is to be expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is a scoped [enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).  As such, there are restrictions on conversion to the type that do not exist for fundamental types like `char`.

Because the underlying type of `std::byte` is `unsigned char`, you can't convert a (signed) `char` to a `byte` during initialization because the conversion is a narrowing conversion.

One solution is to use a vector of `unsigned char` to store the file content.  Since a `byte` is not an arithmetic type, many of the numeric operations do not exist for `byte` (only the bitwise ones).

If you must use `std::byte`, define the iterator and fstream using that type:

```
typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<std::byte> file_iterator;

std::basic_ifstream<std::byte> file(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```