# What is the difference between ostream and basic_ostream<unsigned char>?

Tags: c++

Is practice, what is the difference between

```
ostream stream( ... );
```

and

```
basic_ostream<unsigned char> stream( ... );
```

when dealing with binary data?

Comment: Basically none what so ever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should a buffer of bytes be signed or unsigned char buffer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653336/should-a-buffer-of-bytes-be-signed-or-unsigned-char-buffer)

Comment: You mean *besides* the default data type override propagated through to the streambuf and char_traits subordinates? Nothing. They're the identical code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of `ostream` in your headers, it should be templated on `char` (which is usually signed by default). Obviously it's the same size as an `unsigned char`, so it should behave the same way with raw binary data. The signed/unsigned distinction doesn't affect the underlying representation or processing at all.